# Should I display Restore subscription button?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore, subscription

Is there really need in this button? When I verify a receipt and discover there is valid subscription, doesn't it uniquely say, that the subscription is valid and there is no need to run restore process? Or may be there are some cases when it's not possible to determine whether the user had the subscription, for instance on other device?

Comment: You can  follow my answer in the question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692959/in-app-purchase-restore-purchases-button-on-user-bound-purchase/49693230?noredirect=1#comment86399104_49693230

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-App Purchase: "Restore Purchases" button on user-bound purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692959/in-app-purchase-restore-purchases-button-on-user-bound-purchase)

Answer (score 0):

**Your app will be rejected if you submit it with In App Purchases but no Restore button**. Even if you have an home-made checking and don't see the goal of the button, add it.

If you try to submit it without Restore button you'll get this rejection message from Apple :

> We found that your app offers In-App Purchase/s that can be restored
>   but it does not include a "Restore" feature to allow users to restore
>   the previously purchased In-App Purchase/s.
>
> To restore previously purchased In-App Purchase products, it would be
>   appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore
>   process when the "Restore" button is tapped.

Don't play with Apple rules :)