# In-App Purchases: Restoring Purchases Server Side

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

iOS requires all apps have "Restore Purchase" functional through StoreKit or they are rejected. If my app keeps track of purchases on the server side do I still need this button? It would effectively do nothing if I'm thinking of this correctly since all of my in app purchases are managed at the user account level server side.

Comment: You might be able to appeal against the rejection using the logic you just presented here. Have you tried doing this through iTunesConnect?

Comment: If you only have consumable in app purchases then a restore button is not required, however Apple recommends that you provide some mechanism for the user to "restore" unconsumed purchases in The event that they move to another device or re-install their device. I.e. you can provide a user account system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54153169/3166209

In summary:

> If you have your own account based system, you aren't required to
>   restore purchases from the device receipt if they can be restored by
>   logging in to their (your) account. You're required you to have
>   restore functionality, but it doesn't have to be implemented through
>   StoreKit. Apple vaguely mentions this in their docs as do service
>   providers.

You'll notice large, cross-platform, subscription apps like Netflix don't have a restore purchases button anywhere. This is because restoring purchases with the device receipt could allow a single receipt to be shared across multiple users that log-in on the same device.