# User can restore the same purchase on different accounts

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

In my app user can log in with a phone number (account) and purchase auto-renewable subscription. This subscription will be associated with his account so he can log in on another device and see his purchased items. The problem is that he can log in with different phone numbers (accounts) on the same device where the subscription was purchased and restore purchases. So he can restore purchased item for other accounts using the same subscription.

Question: Can we remove Restore Purchases functionality in that case? If we can't how can we handle such situations?

I heard that all apps in Store should have restore purchase button but it doesn't make sense in our case.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54153169/3166209

In summary, you're required you to have restore functionality, but it doesn't have to be implemented through StoreKit. You'll notice large, cross-platform, subscription apps like Netflix don't have a restore purchases button anywhere for the exact reason you mentioned.